# Load Admob interstitial programmatically in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, admob

I'm trying to load Admob interstitials programmatically in a Phonegap app.

I'm using a plugin that I found on Github:

https://github.com/admob-google/admob-phonegap

I built a test app with the example html provided in the repo. The only problem is that I want to be able to cache the interstitial and load it programmatically. The example uses buttons to trigger the Javascript.

I did get the ads to work in the app, but only by pressing the buttons. I would like to trigger the interstitial on Game Over in a HTML 5 game. No user interaction required.

This is what I've tried:

```
 function onLoad(){

   admob.cacheInterstitial();

   document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady, false);
}

 function onDeviceReady() {
    showInterstitial();
}


<body onload="onLoad();">
```

However, it doesn't work. I admit Javascript isn't my strong point and have a much easier time with Objective-C and Swift.

Maybe someone better at Javascript than me can point me in the right direction on how to trigger these functions `admob.cacheInterstitial();` and `showInterstitial();` programmatically.

Here is the full example HTML I am using:

https://github.com/admob-google/admob-phonegap/blob/master/Example/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider use this plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova
The use is very simple! I actually use in my game and it works perfectly!

You just need to include the follow code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
    tappxShare:           0.5,                                        // Optional
    autoShowInterstitial: false
  });



  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true, that's why we set to false! so we can call when we want!)
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

And inside your gameOver function, you just use the follow code to call the interstitial ad

```
admob.showInterstitialAd();
```

***UPD**: Using your plugin, try to use a bool and show this function, maybe like this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if(boolGameOver){
        showInterstitial();
        boolGameOver = false;
    }
}
```

And in your gameOverFunction, call onDeviceReady function, after you set boolGameOver to true!

Comment: Ok, great. I will try this method. I ended up using a Native method to get the app showing ads, but will try this Cordova method.

Comment: @Paul i update my answer, check if it works to your plugin!

Comment: Hey Han, I tried your code but I get these messages in the console:  `AppFeelReachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags` and `<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"TEST_DEVICE_NUMBER" ];`